# EF Code First - Identity & Computed column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have created one entity called 'Item'. It got an Id, CreateDate and ModifyDate along with some required data.

I am using EF 4.3 Code First model. I am ok to go with latest version of EF if it resolves my problem.

All these three values are optional. Sometimes, I may pass some values say Id or CreateDate. I want EF to generate those value automatically from DB if I don't pass, otherwise take the one that I have passed.

So far I found, If I make Id column as Identity column then it ignores supplied values, same is true for computed column.

Is there anyway I will have option to supply those value?

One more thing, I have modify date field. I want DB to update the current date time whenever I update the record. I found following options, But somehow I am not comfortable with any of them. Is there any direct option from DB (something like default value)?

1. Use the Update trigger to update the modifydate
2. Set the modifydate value at C# side

My entity:

```
public class Item
{  
    public Guid? ItemId { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> All these three values are optional. Sometimes, I may pass some values
>   say Id or CreateDate. I want EF to generate those value automatically
>   from DB if I don't pass, otherwise take the one that I have passed.

This is not possible in EF. EF supports only two mechanisms:

- Value is always provided by the application
- Value is always provided by the database by using either identity or computed setting

The reason is the way how default values are handled by database. They are used only if INSERT command doesn't set the column explicitly but EF always sets all columns explicitly (even if you didn't set the value because default .NET value is used) except columns marked with identity or computed setting.

So the third mechanism is needed for your scenario:

- Set default values with trigger if they are not present or contain .NET default value

The problem is that without marking properties as computed or identity you will not get those values back automatically. If you insert a new record or update existing record your entity instance will still contain old values (or default .NET values) unless you force a new query to database to refresh current entity. That is why identity and computed settings exists - to get those values back during insert or update automatically.

When you are using EF all these changes should be made in your application, not in the database by triggers.

Answer (score 0):

- You can set default values in the constructor of `Item`.
- For modification dates I'd always use a database trigger, because you don't want to depend on clocks on different machines.

Comment: Yes, we can do it using constructor, but I want to get it from DB due to the same reason you have mentioned later that want to depend on DB clock rather than different machines.

Comment: Yes, of course. The ItemId could still be set by constructor and create date by an insert trigger.